# How do I convert a unix date from URL to datetime for update field?

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following line that currently updates a field on one of my forms. It takes the unix date code from the URL and uses it as value =.

Which is all fine but the settings wants the format to be like the following Date format - 18-06-2015 09:01:45

```
<input autocomplete='off' class='input-small' tabindex='3' type="text" name="jform[incident]" id="jform_incident" value="<?php echo (isset($_GET["entered"])) ? $_GET["entered"] : ""; ?>"; ;maxlength='50' size="25">
```

Is there a way to update the following part of the code so it shows in the date format described above rather than the unix timestamp?

```
value="<?php echo (isset($_GET["entered"])) ? $_GET["entered"] : ""; ?>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to format your unix timestamps into the appropriate format.

For example:

```
<?php

$timestamp = $_GET["entered"];  //this is your unix timestamp.

date('n-j-Y H:i:s', $timestamp)
```

The `'n-j-Y H:i:s'` define thes the format you want outputted.  What each letter represents is listed on the [PHP date() function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters).

You code would look something like this if implemented:

```
value="<?php echo (isset($_GET["entered"])) ? date('n-j-Y H:i:s', $timestamp) : ""; ?>"
```

Comment: php `date()` has definition like  `date($format, $timestamp)`

Comment: Cool that works almost: For some reason it is making the time CDT instead of GMT. So if I have a time 20-06-2015 23:52:55 taken from the previous page which shows in the url as 1434844375. I have checked it on an online converter and it shows the original date. The time on the form when added shows it as 20-06-2015 6:52:55 which when adding a T to the variable shows it is CDT time not GMT. '

Comment: Got it - I changed the date to gmdate.. Awsome.. Thanks for you help
 value="<?php echo gmdate('d-m-Y H:i:s', $_GET["entered"]); ?>";

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP Date function, and pass the unix timestamp as a second parameter:

```
date('n-j-Y H:i:s', $_GET["entered"]);
```

For more information about the formatting, check:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks Axel for heading me in the right direction.

I wanted to update a field on my form with the GMT time taken from the Unix timestamp contained in the url. So I could relate the entry to a specific event entered on another form. I have learnt heaps.

My final code for this input box was,

```
<input autocomplete='off' class='input-small' tabindex='3' type="text" name="jform[incident]" id="jform_incident" value="<?php echo gmdate('d-m-Y H:i:s', $_GET["entered"]); ?>"; ;maxlength='50' size="25">
```

This peice of code now takes the unix timestamp stored as entered="what ever the timestamp was" from the URL using $_GET inside gmdate which returns the GMT time of the corresponding incident. This is entered as the value in the field.

Thank you so much, I can now get on with finishing my component.